# How could Han Solo possibly fall for Luke's con?

Tags: star-wars

> Luke: She's rich.
>
> Han Solo: [interested] Rich?
>
> Luke: **Rich, powerful**. Listen, if you were to rescue her, the reward
>   would be...
>
> Han Solo: What?
>
> Luke: Well, more wealth than you can imagine!
>
> Han Solo: I don't know, I can imagine quite a bit.

Aaaand... the cynical, hard-bitten, seen-all-sorts-of-treachery, experienced smuggler Han Solo conveniently fails to notice that Princess of just-blown-to-bits Alderaan is **no longer is powerful or rich**, being that her "fiefdom" got destroyed and the Rebellion is dirt poor (which he knows quite well, after his ex-gf swindled him and his smuggler buddies out of money to fund that same Rebellion).

**Is there any canon explanation for why he got conned by a naïve farmer kid?**

An obvious explanation could be that he didn't know Leia was a princess of Alderaan... but she wasn't a nobody Princess Vespa - **she was an Imperial Senator**.

Comment: He used The Force? (Latent abilities?)

Comment: I can't possibly imagine that in a galaxy-spanning society - especially one where her home would be a likely target of Imperial lockdown, that she - or anyone with half a brain would keep all of her assets in one place or even on one planet. Just because her planet was blown up, doesn't mean she wouldn't have credits either in off-world accounts or hidden elsewhere.

Comment: @phantom42 - FYI - based on everything we know of C-canon, she (unlike some other Alderaanian exiles) really was pretty poor. Whether Han knew that during ANH is a different story

Comment: @DaveNay - interesting guess... but is there canon support for that?

Comment: Sure, but that's C-Canon, and Luke wouldn't know that. He just knows, "Hey, she's a princess, that probably means she's rich!" (How he knows that, as you've pointed out, is a separate issue.)

Comment: @DVK....IDK, that's why it's a comment not an answer.:-)

Comment: @phantom42 - this question assumes Luke was just making s*(& up. Unlike Solo, he was a bumpkin from Nowhere, Wiskonsin (errr.... Tattooine) so he didn't know who was who in the Galaxy.

Comment: What con? She's just inherited a gazillion space dollars from her dead relatives. ..

Comment: @Richard - wut?

Comment: The perils of auto complete

Comment: "You needn't worry about your reward. If money is all you love, then that's what you'll receive." -Leia Organa, ANH. Doesn't seem to be much of a con.

Comment: Besides the obvious (it _is not_ a con, it's perfectly plausible for a princess to be rich, and she is indeed) this is the kind of excuse that Solo needs to justify to his good-aligned rogue self do what he would do for free (or for a kiss) anyway. But being a smuggler, he cannot simply do something good without losing his face.

Comment: "Were not just doing this for money... were doing it for a shit load of money!"

Comment: Some of the later Star Wars books note that many Alderaan survivors became quite wealthy, because the decentralised Imperial financial system meant that all of Alderaan's wealth wasn't on Alderaan. And there were a limited number of survivors to inherit that wealth.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, found an actual canon answer.

He **DID NOT** fall for the con - he **figured out the obvious problem immediately**, and Luke had to clarify his explanation to account for Alderaan's destruction, providing a plausible motivation for Han. And even then, Han was dubious to an extent.

*"Star Wars: A New Hope, Lucas novelization from 1976 (ghost written by Alan Dean Foster based on the script)* says:

> “She’s a rich and powerful Senator,” Luke pressed, hoping an appeal to Solo’s baser instincts might be more effective. “If we could save her, the reward could be substantial.”
>
> “Uh … rich?” Then Solo **looked disdainful. “Wait a minute … Reward, from whom? From the government on Alderaan?” He made a sweeping gesture toward the hangar and by implication the space where Alderaan had once orbited**.
>
> Luke thought furiously. “If she’s being held here and is scheduled to be executed, that means she must be dangerous in some way to whoever destroyed Alderaan, to whoever had this station built. You can bet it had something to do with the Empire instituting a reign of full repression.
>
> “**I’ll tell you who’ll pay for her rescue, and for the information she holds. The Senate, the rebel Alliance, and every concern that did business with Alderaan. She could be the sole surviving heir of the off-world wealth of the entire system!** The reward could be more wealth than you can imagine.”
>
> “I don’t know … I can imagine quite a bit.” He glanced at Chewbacca, who grunted a terse reply. Solo shrugged back at the big Wookiee. “All right, we’ll give it a try. **But you’d better be right about that reward**. What’s your plan, kid?”
>
> Luke was momentarily taken aback. All his energies up till now had been concentrated on persuading Solo and Chewbacca to aid in a rescue attempt. That accomplished, Luke became aware he had no idea how to proceed. He had grown used to old Ben and Solo giving directions. Now the next move was up to him.

Answer (score 43):

How is it a con? The situation played out exactly as described: they rescued the princess, and Han got a handsome payoff (we see him loading boxes of cash as he prepares to leave Yavin).

Comment: Because Luke had absolutely no idea whether Leia was really rich and powerful when he was talking to Han. Also, Han was paid out of Alliance funds, NOT by Leia.

Comment: I agree with this. Even if he knew her home planet had been destroyed, it was hardly likely that Princess (and Senator) Leia was penniless.

Comment: @Richard - Luke **didn't have a clue** she was a Senator.

Comment: @DVK - Perhaps the midichlorians told him...

Comment: Not sure why it matters she is a Senator when she is already a princess - and that is right there in the title.  And even if Leia was penniless, royalty does not exist in a vacuum - having potentially the last, or one of the last remaining Alderaan nobles on your starship is going to be worth something.  If Leia couldn't pay him, a guy with Han's connections could find someone who would (in exchange for Leia herself).

Luke would really only be conning Han if Leia wasn't a princess.

Comment: He didnt know her planet was destroyed until it was too late and he was stuck being pulled in by the death star.

Comment: @DVK How do you know that Alliance paid Han? It's Galactic economy. Why couldn't Leia have assets and investments in other systems?

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 - on a moon of Yavin? WHAT investments? Trees?

Comment: @DVK Didn't expect this comment... She could have investments on Coruscant for example.

Comment: @joshbirk This *is* a universe with *elected monarchs with hereditary titles,* so it's anyone's guess how powerful the last remaining member of a noble family might be. (Seriously, who would vote in a 14-year old?)

Answer (score 30):

Prior to its untimely demise, Alderaan was a center of commerce and culture in the Core Worlds.  It had a long and rich history, it was a famed tourist destination, and it was a strong presence in the Senate.  Leia was well-known as the youngest Senator in history, and it's entirely conceivable that Han would have at least heard of her.

That sort of political power doesn't come without at least some degree of material wealth, and much of it would have been off-world.  Leia or her family owned or controlled more wealth than Han dreamed of (and he can dream of a lot).  Even including his ship, his total net worth was significantly lower than Leia's, even after Alderaan's destruction.  He had every reason to expect she could have paid him a handsome reward.

He was also desperate for money.  He owed Jabba money, 10,000 or more credits.  That's almost enough to buy a small ship.  He also had operating expenses - ships need parts, fuel, and supplies.  Oxygen scrubbers need changing, engines need grease, etc.  To keep flying, he needed cash.  He was in dire need and the money he had so far gotten for the trip (a paltry 2 thousand, since they never reached Alderaan to get the remaining 15) were going to barely cover his expenses, let alone debts.

Given that his life was already in extreme danger (trapped on the Death Star) and his future looked bleak (no way to pay Jabba) he was willing to take the chance.  He didn't get played by Luke, Luke just reminded him of a fact that he, in his melancholy state, had forgotten: there was still a chance to get paid and save his hide.  And it wasn't really that much more dangerous to go to a prison area (where the guards were worried about escape, not break-ins) rather than staying in a conquered guard tower (where shift changes or random security sweeps could occur without notice, and they'd be immediately suspect).

Comment: I'm almost certain some of the (now non-canon) EU books made reference to "long lost relatives" trying to claim family wealth...

Comment: Also, remember, he did get paid.

Comment: @Himarm For all we know, Alderaan was insured.

Comment: @Himarm Most insurers pay out before suing the guilty party for damages, so there's good odds Leia would have been able to collect on the policy even if the Emperor refused to pay. (That said, when the Emperor orders a corporation to be dissolved, 'dissolved' might not be a euphemism; They could potentially be rendered incapable of paying outstanding claims if he moved quickly enough.)

Comment: @Himarm They may well be required to pay out even if there's no chance for them to recoup the loss by suing for damages;It depends on the terms and conditions of the insurance policy. On that note, if the policy was sold before Palpatine took over, it probably wouldn't have included an "act of Sith Lord" clause; GalactInsure could potentially go bankrupt from this one.

Answer (score 14):

Han didn't get conned by a naif farmer kid.  He got persuaded by a powerful force-sensitive who honestly believed what he was saying, with whom he was already in cahoots.

1. Luke wasn't trying to con, he was offering a sincere argument.  Being cynical and hard-bitten, Han would know how to tell the difference between the two.
2. Luke's father was astonishingly powerful, and having some amount of the same predisposition to the force is the only explanation for how Luke ever managed to best Vader at all.  That surely helped in the persuasion, just as it helped him nail womp-rats back home.
3. The hardest part IRL of pulling a con is putting on a convincing demeanor, and suppressing all of the subconcious ways your mind betrays the fact that you're lying.  Luke didn't have to do that, which gives him a leg up in being believed by Han.
4. Considering that by the time of this conversation they were already in the Death Star, it wasn't a large risk to go to a different highly-secured part of the highly-secured military installation they were already in.  Not being next to their ship for a bit would also likely help avoid the imperial patrols.

Comment: If that word pops up more, I'll really have to look it up. (I thought it was a misspelling at first.)

Comment: @MrLister: [naif](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/naif): naive or unsophisticated.

Answer (score 3):

It's more than that. This isn't a con in any sort of way, as that isn't who Luke is.
My Dad talked about it once with me when I asked about it and this is what he told me:
"He's not a Scoundrel. Not really, and anybody who claims to be one isn't one for long. It's a taxing existence. It takes something out of you. In the case of Han it was Hope. That's why he's so cynical. He's burned his bridges with the Empire. He's got a bounty on his head from his own employers because he had to do what he had to do to stay alive. On top of that, he's broke, the Falcon's broke and the only friend he's got is Chewie. So in truth, what he saw in Luke is hope. This is kid who hasn't been beaten down in life as much as him. Who's still got somekind of innocence left in him. That's why he decided to stick with him. Why he asked him to come along with him when he was about to join in what was basically a suicide mission. And why he decided to come back and help him when he could've taken off with what he had.
He's a scoundrel because he's been forced to be one. What he needs is someone to remind him who he once was and what he could become again. A New Hope in a way."
There you go.

Answer (score 2):

Also... although Han is wit and cunning, he is often drawn by it's "hero role" passions.

It's not Luke who tricks him into the job, it's the story, the legend writting in it's head wich made him accept the job.

Han is driven by some type of "unknown palladin paradigma"... he will try to run with the money when things heaten up, but on the end he always do the right thing. He maybe think of itself as a burglar, but he's in fact, a hero.

So the idea of rescuing a princess automatically sparks in his mind translating a boring and dangerous mission into a heroic crusade. He was only cheated by it's heroic nature.